# Confusing Comparatives (as few ~ as, as many ~ as)

Tags: comparatives

I am very confused with the following sentences and I would like to ask you all what you think.

I have ***as many*** books ***as*** you do.

This means, if ***you*** have 6 books, ***I*** have 6 books too. I get this. Then if you say,

I have ***one third as many*** books ***as*** you do.

Question 1) Does this mean, if ***you*** have 6 books, do ***I*** have 8? (=6 + 6*(1/3)) or 2?(=6 * (1/3))

How does this meaning change if I switch the ***many*** with ***few***?

I have ***one third as few*** books ***as*** you do.

Question 2) Does this mean, if ***you*** have 6 books, do ***I*** have 4? (=6 - (6*(1/3))

Can anyone explain this to me?  Also, I haven't really heard anyone say ***as few ~ as***. Do you guys not use this at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "**How many** books do you have?"
>   "I have six books."
>   "Well, I have one third **as many**."

This means that I have one third of six, or two (2) books.

This is no different than saying that you're going to eat a one-pound burger and I'm going to eat a third *as much* as you, or a one-third-pound burger.

Note that this addresses your question about *as much*. With books that are countable we say *as many*. But with a single unit (like a burger or a glass of water), it's only *measurable*, so it's *as much* instead.

---

> "I have six books."
>   "And I have one third **fewer**."

This means that I have two thirds of six, or four (4) books.

And referring to the single burger, whose portions are *measured* but not *counted*, I could say that I ate one third *less*, or a two-third-pound burger.